# Using NavigationController and changing views within it, without pushing the Nav stack

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.5

I am trying to be able to change content within a NavController without pushing onto the NavController.  For example, if I have a viewcontroller "A", when the user gestures or clicks continue, the view changes to another view controller "X", however the navcontroller does not push the view controller "X" onto its stack. Thus, I could potentially gesture or click continue to display viewController x , y and z. However, at any point I can press back on the Navbar and it will return me back to the previous viewController on its stack

To clarify, I want to be able to implement a page controller that does not affect the navigation controller, thus at any point, if the user pressed back, they return to previous viewcontroller on the stack.

In the image, the view controller that is on the navcontroller is shown. I want to be able to change between different views via pagecontroller within the whitesection.  So i drag and droped an UIView there.  Can I hook that UIview to a viewcontroller and than implement a page controller or how exactly could I go about changing the white section without affecting the navcontroller.   Thanks for everything!

[image]

Comment: Why dont you present "X" as a model view controller in that case? And when you want to move to y and z, you can dismiss "X" and push other views.

Comment: [UINavigationController setViewControllers:viewController animated:YES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the views that are at the top (or anywhere within) the "stack" of view controllers via this method: [`[UINavigationController setViewControllers: animated: ]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a).

Replace the view controller you want to use instead and set "animated" to "NO" if you've already displayed the view controller some other way.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted these other controllers, x, y, and z to be on the stack at all. If you don't, then you can add them as child view controllers of one of the controllers that is on the stack, and this will have no effect on the back button action -- it will still take you back to the previous controller (that you pushed from). It can be done like this:

```
 -(IBAction)addBlue:(id)sender {
        BlueController *blue = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Blue"];
        [self addChildViewController:blue];
        [self.blue didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        blue.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:blue.view];
    }
```

Comment: This is correct however, I am not using storyboard, thus how can I achieve this with xib.

Comment: @EthanKeiser, You just replace the storyboard instantiation with [[ alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNibName Here" bundle:nil] to instantiate your new controller